# Maven Dependency-List in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, list, maven, plugins, dependencies

### Dependency-List

I am programming a Code with Maven in Eclipse which is supposed to get all Dependencies of a Project.
Therefore I included the Maven-Dependency-Plugin 2.8 into my Project.
This Plugin provides a method `mvn Dependency:List` which I want to use in Eclipse.

The question is: What Code do i need, so that Dependency-List is working properly in my Project?

PS: I found the class ListMojo that appears to have the right function.
The Problem is, that i don't know how to go on.
Feel free to request more information if they are needed.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Nils

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply call that Maven target on a command line and parse the resulting report? That seems much easier than trying to actually load Maven and some Maven plugin Java code to directly execute the same functionality.